# WPF- Is there a way to bind to the SelectedValues of both a TreeView and a ListBox?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview, listbox

I need to bind so that the Content of a content control is set to the SelectedValue of either the TreeView or the ListBox. The SelectedValue that was most recently changed should provide the content for the ContentControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working using the following concept.

1. Bind the content control to a read only property "SelectedItem" (with private property _selectedItem).
2. Bind the ListBox.SelectedItem to a read/write property "SelectedItemLB".
3. In the SelectedItemLB setter, set the value of _selectedItem, and raise the PropertyChanged event for SelectedItem.
4. Create a handler for VreeView.SelectedItemChanged, which sets the value of _selectedItem and raises the PropertyChanged event for SelectedItem.

Here is my full code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.items = new List<object>();
            this.items.Add(new Car("Green"));
            this.items.Add(new Car("Blue"));
            this.items.Add(new Car("Red"));

            this._selectedItem = this.items[0];
            this.treeView1.SelectedItemChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(treeView1_SelectedItemChanged);
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        void treeView1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            this._selectedItem = treeView1.SelectedItem;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedItem"));
        }
        private List<object> items;

        public List<object> Items
        {
            get { return items; }
            set { items = value; }
        }


        public object SelectedItemLB
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedItem"));
                }
            }
        }

        private object _selectedItem;
        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

The XAML is pretty simple:

```
<StackPanel>

    <ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItemLB, Mode=TwoWay}" ></ListBox>
    <TreeView Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Color}"></ContentControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do that directly. However there are several straightforward solutions.

**A. Use events to set the `Content`**

Simply attach a common handler to the `SelectedValueChanged` events of your `ItemsControl`s. Whenever one of them changes its selection, the handler will set the `Content` to whatever was selected. I think this is most simple.

**B. Use intermediary properties**

Bind the `SelectedValue` of each `ItemsControl` to a property. In the property's setter, also set the `Content` equal to `value`. This allows you to use data binding instead of event handlers, but it still requires you to write code-behind and it doesn't buy you much. Of course, if you are already binding to properties for other purposes, there is almost no extra cost (only an assignment in each setter) so this method might be preferable.